# SwiftUI Grid Images Can't be Tapped to Show DetailView

Tags: ios, swiftui

I'm trying to create a collection view in SwiftUI. I can create the grid (of images in 
this case) but I have not found a way to click an image and transition to another view - 
neither a modal nor a full view. I am storing the images in CoreData and am using a
method from Paul Hudson to break the images into rows:

https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/language/how-to-split-an-array-into-chunks

This code does allow transitions, but with a single click it cycles through each of the images in the HStack
row even though each photo has its own NavigationLink wrapper.

I have also tried a version where I made the grid from buttons and put the images into
the buttons. That was worse - the detail content was not correct and Xcode complained
mightily that: "Warning: Attempt to present <*>  on <*> which is already presenting (null)."
I also tried adding .onTapGesture{} to each image. Similar failure as the buttons.

```
struct ChunkedContentView: View {

    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
    @FetchRequest(fetchRequest: DermPhoto.getAllDermPhotos()) var dermPhotos: FetchedResults<DermPhoto>

    //@State private var columnCount = 3//hard coded to 3 at the moment
    @State private var showDetailView = false

    var body: some View {

        let chunkThis = DermPhoto.chunkTheDermPhotos()

        return GeometryReader { geo in
            NavigationView {
                List {
                    ForEach(0 ..< chunkThis.count) { index in
                        HStack {
                            ForEach(chunkThis[index]) { p in
                                NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(passedDerm: p)) {

                                Image(uiImage: UIImage(data: p.myImage!)!)
                                    .resizable()
                                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                                    .frame(width: ((geo.size.width / 3) - 15), height: ((geo.size.width / 3) - 15))
                                    .border(Color.black)
                                    .clipped()
                                    //comment out NavigationLink and this does not work either
                                    //.onTapGesture {
                                    //self.showDetailView.toggle()
                                    //}
                                    //.sheet(isPresented: self.$showDetailView) {
                                    //DetailView(passedDerm: p)
                                    //}
                                    //either above or nav link
                                }//nav link
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                .navigationBarTitle("Time Series")
            }//nav
        }//geo
    }
}
```

As a second question, is there a way to disable showing the disclosure indicator of a
NavigationLink?

Any guidance would be appreciated. Xcode 11.3 (11C29)

Comment: Just use `ScrollView` instead of `List` in your code snapshot and all works (as well as chevron /disclosure indicator/ have gone)

Comment: Wow. Amazingly simple. Changing to ScrollView causes my images to be replaced with blue squares for some reason. I changed the call to p.myImage to a static system image and it works just as you describe. While my images are gone, the data in the detail view is correct, so I am getting the Core Data entity, but something in the change from List to ScrollView is affecting the display of the images.

Comment: While it seems very strange, if I add .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle()) to the NavigationLink the images show as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Asperi deserves the credit - use `ScrollView` instead of `List`. That also removes the disclosure indicator. If you use images you need to add  `.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())` to the **NavigationLink**. If you use system icons you may not need that step.